# Is injecting DbContextOptions an anti-pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm, entity-framework-core

When creating WPF apps, I tend to have the ViewModel inject DbContexts into the service classes, upon creation.

However, things would be a lot cleaner, if I could inject a service class into the ViewModel. But this would introduce the risk of long lived DbContexts, if a user stays on the same view for too long.

A way to solve this could be to pre-define the `DbContextOptions` and then inject that to the service from the ViewModel. And then have the service initialize `DbContext` only when it’s needed, using those options. This would allow testing via `InMemory` and prevent long lived contexts. To me it sounds like a win-win situation... Except I have never seen anyone else do it, which is usually a warning sign.

Have I missed something? Is this an anti-pattern or code smell?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Create a DbContext factory that would resolve the desired context and handle the options injection

Comment: Good point. I’ll consider rephrasing my question, to make it clear what my problem is.

Comment: @Nkosi Why should one do that? `DContext` is just a class which has dependency to `DbContextOptions<TContext>` which is injected to it via constructor. Hence any other class registered with dependency to `DbContextOptions<TContext>`will be resolved the same way.

Comment: @IvanStoev The OP's concern was about capturing the context for long periods. By injecting the factory and only using it when needed in a function, you can ensure that the context goes out of scope

Comment: @Nkosi My point was that there is no need of special factory, because `DbContextOptions<TContext>` is the only dependency needed for creating `TContext` instances, hence *is* sort of a factory. EF Core `AddDbContext` is just a shortcut for registering both options and context classes.

Comment: @IvanStoev I agree. My concern was more on the BdContext becoming captured variable.

Comment: @IvanStoev The OP's focus on injecting the options is also why I mentioned the XY Problem as there may have been a misunderstanding of the topic

Comment: @IvanStoev my wording of saying factory was the wrong term to use.

Comment: @Nkosi Could be. But taking literally the question from title "Is injecting DbContextOptions an anti-pattern?", I would say "No, because this is already used by DbContext service" :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev They were more referring to injecting the options into other classes/Services in order to then pass it to a DbContext initialized locally. That is the confusion there. I was suggesting to just resolve the context and the options would be injected into the context automatically by the DI container.